# Negation of a regex

Tags: regex

I am trying to negate a regex.
I have a sentence, say, `"Do you #know this, please #help"`.
By using the regex `#\w*`, I can extract the words: `#know` and `#help`. 
What is the regex to be used to extract remaining words? 
Something like a negation of `#\w*`. 
I am using regex option in Rapid Miner tool and thus I do not have other functions of any programming language.

Comment: Not every extraction is doable by regular expressions. Sometimes, they are not the right tool to use

Comment: Here you go ... `(?<![\w#])\w+`

Comment: This pattern worked. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Which pattern worked, this one `(?<![\w#])\w+` ?

Comment: Yes. Also, the pattern which is given by @aquinas.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try: `\b(?<!#)(\w+)`

[**Demo**](https://regexr.com/3pc1q)

Match a word boundary but only if the first character in the word is NOT a # and then match word characters.

Comment: I am working with the tool mentioned but just to check the regex, am using python. So I gave - pattern = "\b(?<!#)(\w+)" and text = "Do you #know this, please #help". The command re.findall(pattern,text,re.IGNORECASE), gave the output - [] . The desired output is as it is in 'Demo' link.

Comment: Try `pattern = r"\b(?<!#)(\w+)"`

Answer (score 0):

I cannot give you a solution here, but I can recommend you a good website to create your very own regular expression. Since I got to know, that the regex used here is based on the perl syntax, you could make use of this Regular Expression Generator to solve your problem. Just remember to set "Perl" as your flavor for your expression.
Best of luck!

[Regex101](https://regex101.com)

Comment: Since It isn't an answer, this should be posted as a comment.

Comment: ... And still you don't have enough rep to post a comment, then you **still** shouldn't post a comment as an answer

Answer (score 0):

I am not very clear what you are asking for. However, I came up with the following fiddle. Please check [this](https://regex101.com/r/ZKX2O9/1/) out

Here is what I did:

```
((?<=#)\w*)|(?!#)\w*
   |    |     |   +--> A word  
   |    |     +------> Only match the above word if # is not in front of it
   |    +------------> A word
   +-----------------> Only match the above word if there is # in front of it
```

(First one is a positive lookbehind and the second expression is a negative lookbehind.)

I combined these two conditions with a pipe(|) but you don't need to. If you need matching words separately, you need to do 2 sets of regex expressions.

Comment: I tried this and got output as - ['', '', '', '', 'know', '', '', '', '', '', '', 'help', '']

Answer (score 0):

This gets the remaining words `(?<![\w#])\w+`

https://regex101.com/r/QXkg14/1